# Customize chart points on c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I would like to have a area chart with empty ( no filled inside) points.

I've been trying to customize my own CSS, but it seems impossible to make what i want.

Only one way which I found - add function to my chart:

```
onrendered={() => {
      d3.selectAll("circle")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("stroke", "black");
   }}
```

But when page is loading I  still see for a while filled points.

There is a way to implement no filled points using CSS or without usind onrendered function?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This depends a bit on what they have used internally. If they have used `.attr("fill", "black")` then css should override it, but if they have used `.style("fill", "black")` css won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is fine that all points share the same color, then this is pretty straightforward in plain css, we want to set the stroke to black (or whatever), the stroke width to 1 px, and set the fill to white (none will show the line/area underneath):

```
circle {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: white !important;
}
```

This is a quick demonstration modifying one of the [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJu/4742/) from the c3.js documentation. I've included the css above, and shown how to modify the point radius if you want to balance radius with stroke width differently:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        types:{
          data1: 'line',
          data2: 'area'
        }
    },
    point: {
      r: 3 // default is 2.5
    }
});
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.5.2/c3.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css">

<div id="chart"></div>
```